# How to deserialize this json with Gson?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, gson

I am going to deserialize this `json string` with `Gson`

```
       {
    "ads": [
        {
            "ad": {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "...",
                "publicImage": "...",
                "publicUrl": "...",
                "adposition": {
                    "name": "home"
                },
                "ttl": 30,
                "debug": false
            }
        },
        {
            "ad": {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "...",
                "publicImage": "...",
                "publicUrl": "...",
                "adposition": {
                    "name": "splash"
                },
                "ttl": 30,
                "debug": false
            }
        },
        {
            "ad": {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "...",
                "publicImage": "...",
                "publicUrl": "...",
                "adposition": {
                    "name": "home"
                },
                "ttl": 30,
                "debug": false
            }
        }
    ],
    "message": "issue list generated",
    "status": "success"
}
```

and what I have create for classes is (getter setter has been removed) :

```
public class Ad {

    public class AdPosition{

        private String mName;

        public String getName() {
            return mName;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            mName = name;
        }

    }

    @SerializedName("id")
    private int mID; 
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String mTitle; 
    @SerializedName("publicImage")
    private String mPublicImage; 
    @SerializedName("publicUrl")
    private String mPublicUrl; 
    @SerializedName("ttl")
    private int mTtl; 
    @SerializedName("adposition")
    private AdPosition mAdPosition;     
}
```

and

```
public class AdsListResponse {

    @SerializedName("ads")
    private List<Ad> mAds;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String mMessage;
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String mStatus;
}
```

and for converting I use below code

```
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        AdsListResponse ads = gson.fromJson(response, AdsListResponse.class);

        for(Ad ad : ads.getAds()){
            if(ad.getAdPosition().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("splash")){
                System.out.println(ad.getAdPosition().getName());
        }
```

But my list contains objects(Ad) but every field of them is null, for example it has 3 ad but id,title,... are all null, what should I do?

**Sorry I copied and paste it wrongly, but still the problem is there, my list of Ad contains Ad but each field of Ad is null**

Comment: Your json is not well formed. Try to validate it here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: not according to jsonlint.com

Comment: Ok, now it is valid! Put your code here: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ on the right you'll see the structure of your object, so will be easy to translate it in java class.

Comment: sorry I copy and paste it wrongly in the question, now it is valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyze your JSON

```
{ // an object at the root
"ads": [ // a key value pair, where the value is an array
    { // an object within the array
        "ad": { // a key value pair, where the value is an object

            // bunch of key value pairs, with int, string, boolean or object values
            "id": 1, 
            "title": "...",
            "publicImage": "...",
            "publicUrl": "...",
            "adposition": {
                "name": "home"
            },
            "ttl": 30,
            "debug": false
        }
    },
```

Considering that a JSON object maps to a Java POJO, a JSON string maps to a Java `String`, a JSON array maps to a Java array or `Collection`, and keys maps to fields, let's analyze your POJO classes

```
public class AdsListResponse { // root is an object

    @SerializedName("ads")
    private List<Ad> mAds; // field of type List (Collection) mapping to the array
```

So you've mapped

```
{ // an object at the root
"ads": [ // a key value pair, where the value is an array
    {
```

The next token is

```
"ad": { // a key value pair, where the value is an object
```

You have no POJO where this exists. You'd need something like

```
public class AdWrapper {
    @SerializedName("ad")
    private Ad mAd;
```

and then change the `AdsListResponse` to

```
class AdsListResponse {    
    @SerializedName("ads")
    private List<AdWrapper> mAds;
}
```

to complete the object tree.

Comment: thanks for your help(+1) but I do not understand "You have no POJO where this exists. You'd need something like" so what is my Ad class?

Comment: @mmlooloo Your `Ad` class corresponds to the JSON object in the key value pair where the key is `"ad"`. But you have no Java object to contain that key value pair.